# how to insert a call to a custom function in a cell? (not refreshing function call workaround)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using script or a recorded macro to insert/copy a call to a custom function in a cell causes the call to the function to not work.
The text content of the cell is exactly the same I don't know why it does not works.

I'm writing a script with a function that takes as input a row range and analyzes it returning information I need.
The cell content is
`=customfunction_row(CELL("address";F4)&":"&CELL("address";BO4))`
So the function is invoked correctly and if I drag the cell down with autofill it reads the correct range.
The function works but of course if a cell of the ranges changes value the function is not invoked again and the result does not change.

I don't need it to update itself in real time but only when needed I tried two things, neither of them worked.

First one: I did 2 buttons,

- one labeled "CLEAR" that invokes a function that clears all the content of the columns where the customfunction_row is
- one labeled "REFILL" that invokes that takes the text customfunction_row(CELL("address";F4)&":"&CELL("address";BO4))
  puts a = in front of it and prints it as text in all the column range that was cleared.
  It works as intended: the correct invocation is written in the cell BUT... it throws an error in the script, as is the parameter passed is not of the right type.
  but it is EXACTLY the same cell content as before.

Second one: I use a recorded Macro to do exactly the same thing.
While I record the macro the contentis written in the cells and the customfunction_row works as expected, if I invoke the Macro it does not work.

Any idea?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Just do it as a normal function when you need it.  You can read the entire range with getValues() work on the entire array and then write it all at one time with setValues();  I don't think you can call a custom function is a cell.  However, I have to admit that I hardly ever use cell functions or formulas at all.